# Laravel chain realationships from an eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have an eloquent query which returns a with a `hasMany` relationship. With that relationship, I now need to display data from another relationship. Is this possible with a single query?

My Eloquent query fetching with a relationship;

`$tickets = Tickets::with('ticketQuestions')->where('event_id', $id)->get();`

My `TicketQuestions` model also has the following relationship;

```
public function questions() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Questions::class);
}
```

Is it possible to fetch the questions from the `Questions` model as well?

So that my page can display the tickets, the ticket questions (look up table), and the questions themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so by using the dot notation:

```
$tickets = Tickets::with('ticketQuestions.questions')->where('event_id', $id)->get();
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: A pleasure, happy that I could help.